# Any javascript test framework with browser support and single test run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I know that there has been many questions about javascript test frameworks. But, I'm confusing which one I should choose as all are new to me. I'm now using [Jake](http://jakejs.org) with [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org) alongside [node.js](http://nodejs.org). I uses Jake because it comes with Geddy by default. I'm looking for another better testing framework that meets my following requirements:

1. Single test run ([Mocha](http://mochajs.org) or any other suggestion?)
2. Both CLI and browser support
3. Huge community
4. Use with node.js

I [run into problem with Jake for single test run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27541558/1179841) and so it would be a major requirement. Huge community is also important for me. If tests can be run via browser would be plus.

Comment: This is OT for SO as per the FAQ.

Comment: Off-topic? Programmers who has many experiences on this topic are here and it is something related to programming.

Comment: Recommendations for, and lists of, things, are OT for SO as per the FAQ. Opinions (e.g., "best") are *also* OT for SO as per the FAQ.

Comment: @DaveNewton [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/javascript-unit-test-tools-for-tdd) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5370222/1179841) were not marked as off-topic and were not closed.

Comment: So what? Also note that in 2008, when the question was asked, questions like that were not OT. The nature of *other* questions is not relevant to the nature of *this* question. I don't even understand why there's a discussion here: what I'm saying is *documented policy*.

Comment: Just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think most test runners support your first requirement.

The ones with the biggest communities are [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/), [Mocha](http://mochajs.org) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/). You can run both of them in both browser, CLI, and node.

Comment: I think Jake doesn't support the first requirement.

Comment: Mocha and Jasmine definitely would, I don't know about Jake. It looks like it should be able to, can I see your configs?